# Can't rename pictures

Tags: python

The code below allows me to rename folders but I am unable to rename `.tif` files. I have many `.tif` files in `Crop1`, `Crop2`, `Crop3` that I would like to rename. The code seems to run fine with no errors but the execution is faulty (i.e. `.tif` files does not get renamed).

```
import os
no = 1
dir = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Crop"
path = str(dir) + str(no)
files = os.listdir(path)



for index, file in enumerate(files):
    while no <21:
        if file.startswith("Sub"):
            os.rename(os.path.join(path , file ), os.path.join(path , 'Oligo')) 
        no +=1
        path = str(dir) + str(no)
```

Comment: Your should make sure all file is `.tif` file. Your code only rename the first 21 files .

Comment: @tripleee On Windows, you would get a `FileExistsError` instead of silently overwriting the existing file. But it won't happen here (if the module is run only once) because the directory is different each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value of `path` so the `rename` probably can't find a file in that particular path after the first iteration.  I'm guessing maybe you mean something like

```py
for index, file in enumerate(os.listdir(dir), 1):
    while index < 21:
        if file.startswith("Sub") and file.lower().endswith((".tif", ".tiff")):
            path = dir + str(index)
            os.makedirs(path, exists_ok=True)  # create directory if it's missing
            os.rename(os.path.join(dir, file), os.path.join(path , 'Oligo'))
```

There is obviously a fair amount of guesswork as to what you want your code to actually do, but hopefully this will at least help you find a direction.